# How do I target a specific city audience?

Tags: seo, geotargeting, google-local-search

I have a `.com` domain, and I want to target specific countries and cities.

Is it possible to target a specific city audience?

For example: I want to do SEO for  only some selected cities like: New York, Los Angles, Las Vegas, London, Sydney, Delhi and Paris.

How can I target specific cities? How do I find proper keywords for it?

Comment: Requesting recommendations for tools is considered [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site, hence the edits.

Comment: ok.  hoping that i will get answer of my Question.

Answer (score 1):

On page techniques-

- Use country specific language for non-English countries
- Placement of anchor text from pointing to country specific websites
- Mention your tangible address if possible

Off page techniques-

- Set your preferred location in google webmaster tool
- Get backlinks from target country
- Submit your site on local search engines
- Get listed on local classified websites and directories
- Get listed on Google maps, Yahoo! search marketing, Bing local listing

Answer (score 0):

Target keywords containing the city name in it. Eg: 'cleaning service in New York'.
Only New York residence who need that service will search for this keyword. So You can get more city based traffic. Include the city in keyword and do the keyword research.

If you are doing SEO for local business also concentrate on Google listings. Your business will show up in search results.

If you want to get traffic from a country. It is advised to choose their country level domain name Eg: '`name.in` (india) `name.com.au` (Australia)' etc... People from the particular country will find their country level domain and if they are looking for a local result they will click on your website and will increase your click through rate.