# Targeting audience based on location

Tags: seo, google-local-search

My question has to do with the location of my website's audience.

I moderate a website for a music school in San Diego. I recently moved from San Diego to Honolulu and now the location of the people visiting my website is Honolulu. I did not change any of the code or the keywords. The only difference is where I'm physically uploading content to the website.

Why did this change occur and how do I increase the traffic of people living in San Diego?

I checked [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56897/how-do-i-target-a-specific-city-audience). It touched on the subject, but didn't really answer my question. All I did was upload content from a different location and the location of the people visiting my site instantly changed.

I update the site with FileZilla and I use Google Analytics for statistics.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You didn't change the hosting location?   It isn't hosted on your home computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are in a new location and this is where the traffic spike is from would mean:

- People you are interacting with who live in Honolulu are visiting
  your website
- Your visits to your own website are being tracked in
  google analytics. Best solutions for this are either
  [Excluding internal traffic,](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en) or the Google
  [Opt out plugin](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout)

If you are wanting to pull more traffic from San Diego, I would look to add more San Diego focused content, get links from other relevant websites in San Diego, or be active in San Diego focused music forums/social media.